# Cordova-plugin-purchase "store" is undefined on android

Tags: vue.js, cordova, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework, cordova-plugin-purchase

I use the Quasar Framework. When i try to acces the window.store.register() it gives me an error saying store is undefined.

The funny thing is, if i use the older outdated version of this Plugin (cc.fovea.cordova.purchase) everything works fine, but then i cant pulbish my app to the play store because it a too old Billing Library

It also works on android.

This is exactly what i dit:

> cordova plugin install cordova-plugin-purchase --variable BILLING_KEY="Key124"

```
window.store.register([{ id: 'premium', type: window.store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION}])
```

-> Store is undefined

I CANT access the plugin. Help!

Comment: Are you sure store is being added on the window. Isn't it just an object you can call on directly, that's the impression I get from the repo.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem!
I am using latest v13 and: --
CdvPurchase.store.register()
--
store is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

The global object is now in `CdvPurchase.store`

The plugin used to export the store object globally, in `window.store`. Some users complained that this interferes with other libraries.

If you wish to minimize changes to your code, you can chose to export it globally by doing `window.store = window.CdvPurchase.store`

More information in this [migration guide](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/HOWTO:-Migrate-to-v13)

Comment: I have the same problem but using CdvPurchase.store didn't fix it.
I am using latest v13 and: --
CdvPurchase.store.register()

store is not defined!